# Bootstrap Modal Append Inputs to Form

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm currently using the latest jQuery / Bootstrap 3 libraries after switching away from jQueryUI.

I currently have a form and in this form I have fields like name, address, etc... but I also have a Bootstrap Modal which contains many form checkbox fields which I use to set permissions for the new user I'm adding.

There is no submit button inside of the modal and I rather there not be. However the modal is inside of my form tags.

What I need to happen is when the form is submitted, the inputs from the modal also need to be included when the form is posted.

The ID of my form is `#form` and the ID of my modal is `#myModal`

I've tried several different ideas but each time the form is submitted none of the checkbox data from the modal is submitted.

Some idea's I've been playing with are:

```
$('#myModal').parent().appendTo($('#form'));
$('#myModal').parent(1).appendTo($('#form'));

$('#myModal').parent().appendTo($('form'));
$('#myModal').parent(1).appendTo($('form'));
```

and many others. I've created a GIST which contains my HTML and the JS file I've been testing. In the JS file you can see a lot of my other commented out tests I've tried.

https://gist.github.com/diemuzi/03ec70f7ff4973c5923a

I'm at a loss here, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned you rather not have a submit button in the modal , well the bootrap modal comes packaged with some pretty useful events , have a look **[HERE](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events)** .

you can just retrieve the value of the check boxes or whatever input types you have on fire of the input. the custom events in the bootstap plugins are a pritty pricessless feature .

maybe what you're looking for after all is the `hide.bs.modal` event which according to the doc's is fired when :

> This event is fired immediately when the hide instance method has been
>   called.

so the psedo code would look like :

```
$(document).on('hide.bs.modal' , function(e){
    // go retrive all the values ...
});
```